# How can I import a random number of arguments from command line?

Tags: java, command-line

I have an assignment to create a code that takes a number of command line arguments and determines which are above 50 and which are below or equal to 50. The code is working, except it is taking the first number of the command line and setting that as the total number of arguments. I can see that it is taking the first argument [0] and using that as the number of integers to parse, but I don't understand how to make that a variable based on input.

```
public class Distribution100

{

public static void main(String[] args)

{

    int numberOfArgs = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // Integer n is equal to command line arguments.

int n[] = new int[numberOfArgs];

int[] array = new int[numberOfArgs]; // Establish new array and fill with integers from command line argument.

int low = 0; // Create integer low and set it to zero. This will be used later to count up based on the Command Line Argument values.

int high = 0; // create integer high and set it to zero. This will be used later to count up based on the Command Line Argument values.

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfArgs; i++) 

/*For loop to read through the array and then follow the below steps. "args.length" will run the loop based on how many arguments are entered in the command line argument. */

    {

        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);

            if (array[i] >= 1 && array[i] <= 50) // if the number in the array falls between 1 and 50 do the next step

                {

                    low++; // Increase low integer count by 1

                }

            else if (array[i] > 50 && array[i] <= 100) // If the number in the array falls between 50 and 100 do the next step

                {

                    high++; // Increase low integer count by 1

                }

    }

    System.out.println(low + " Numbers are less than or equal to 50.");

    System.out.println(high + " Numbers are higher than 50.");

    }

}
```

Comment: `args.length` is the number of arguments (no need to pass that to the program).

Comment: "... don't understand how to make that a variable based on input", what do you mean by this?

Comment: Joakim,  Apologies as I see how that statement didn’t really make sense. Basically, I know that it is taking the first command line argument and using that to set the number of loops the for loop will run, but I’m confused about how to make that stop happening and instead of using the first number as an integer that states how many numbers there are in the array, actually count the command line arguments and use THAT number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command-line arguments are already in an array, just use that instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = 0;
    for (String s : args) {
        try {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
            if (i > 50) high++;
            else low++;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.printf("%s is not a number!\n", s);
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("%d numbers are less than or equal to 50.\n", low);
    System.out.printf("%d numbers are higher than 50.\n", high);
}
```

I've also added a few things - a try block that catches strings that are not numbers, and using `printf` instead of `println`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to get it working once I used the `string` for the args.